# Слайдер карусель

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

как сделать карусель.
1) чтобы состоял из двух картинок 
2) Поставить надпись
если есть код скиньте пожалуйста, только чтобы вставил картинки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

[FlexSlider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/index.html) тебе в помощь (он еще и адаптивный)

HTML:

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="slide1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide3.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide4.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });
});
```